# Is it possible to insert a variable as a parameter of startsWith()?

Tags: angular, typescript

```
`<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="one">
        <wcs-select [(ngModel)]="SelectedSerie" placeholder="Série" id="leselectg">
            <ng-container *ngFor="let serie of series">
            <wcs-select-option  *ngIf="serie.type_serie == 'Série'" >
                
                {{ serie.code_serie_materiel }}         
                
            
            </wcs-select-option>
            </ng-container>
        </wcs-select>
        <p>Selected option: {{ SelectedSerie }}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="two">

        <wcs-select placeholder="Sous-série" id="leselectg">
            
            <ng-container *ngFor="let serie of series">
                <wcs-select-option *ngIf="serie.type_serie == 'Sous-Série' && serie.code_serie_materiel.startsWith(SelectedSerie)">
                    
                    {{ serie.code_serie_materiel }}         
                    {{ serie.type_serie }}
                
                </wcs-select-option>
                </ng-container>
        </wcs-select>

    </div>
    <div class="three">
        <wcs-select placeholder="Variantes" id="leselectg">
            <ng-container *ngFor="let serie of series">
                <wcs-select-option *ngIf="serie.type_serie == 'Variante'">
                    
                    {{ serie.code_serie_materiel }}         
                    {{ serie.type_serie }}
                
                </wcs-select-option>
                </ng-container>
        </wcs-select>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to include a Selected Series variable in the parameters of my startsWith however it only works when I include a hard string, is there another way to include a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use string template literals, here is example:

```js
const tmp = 'test';

console.log('testing string'.startsWith(`${tmp}`));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, indeed using the literal templates is a good idea